# How to deal with strange rounding of floats in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

As we all know, floating point arithmetic is not always completely accurate, but how do you deal with its inconsistencies?

As an example, in PHP 5.2.9: <sub>*(this doesn't happen in 5.3)*</sub>

```
echo round(14.99225, 4);  // 14.9923 
echo round(15.99225, 4);  // 15.9923 
echo round(16.99225, 4);  // 16.9922 ??
echo round(17.99225, 4);  // 17.9922 ??
echo round(25.99225, 4);  // 25.9922 ??
echo round(26.99225, 4);  // 26.9923
```

How would you work around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to IEEE754, [enjoy your stay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Use [`bc`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [`gmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) instead.

Answer (score 4):

> how do you deal with its
>   inconsistencies?

- For stuff where exact results based on decimal representation matters (i.e. money), *do not use* IEEE754 floats, you use "bignum" libraries like [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)
- For stuff where you just need your calculations to be *relatively* precise  (like most scientific calculations), you use [numerically stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) algorithms so that the inconsistencies stay in the least significant bits (where they don't matter).