# Rounding using arbitrary precision libraries in PHP

Tags: php, math, floating-point, arbitrary-precision

I asked a question earlier about [how to deal with rounding issues with floating point numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248835/how-to-deal-with-strange-rounding-of-floats-in-php), and was pointed to the [`bc`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [`gmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) libraries.

I've looked at the functions in these libraries but nothing jumped out at me when I was looking for one to round off the number.

**How do you accurately round using these libraries?**

Answer (score 1):

In [**How to ceil, floor and round bcmath numbers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers),  the answer gives you an implementation of `bcround` function, which utilizes its own `bcfloor` and `bcceil` function which seems to work.

As a test, here is what you asked for in your comment.

```
echo bcround(16.99225, 4); // outputs 16.9923
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused here - does this actually use the bc functions for rounding? If I have a number (say 16.99225), how would I use this technique to round to 4 digits?